# Problem: retrieving parent category’s first post

Tags: categories, loop

I have a problem checking if a post's category has a parent category, and if so retrieving the first post post of that category. 
Inside the the_post part:

This is my code:

```
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) {
            $parentcat = $childcat->category_parent;
            $parentcat_name = get_cat_name($parentcat);
    }

    echo "ID of parent category: ".$childcat->category_parent."<br />";
    if ($parentcat) {   // is there a parent? If so, this is a child post:

    $tmp_post = $post;  // assign orginal post to tmp_post variable for later use 

    //link name of parent category to first post in parent category
    global $post;
    $the_slug = 'my_slug';
    $args = array( 
        'category' => $parentcat, 
        'numberposts' => 1, 
        'order' => 'ASC' 
        ); 
    $my_posts = get_posts($args);
    if( $my_posts ) {
    $parentpost_link = $my_posts[0]->guid;
    }
        ?>  
        <h2 class='cat-parent'><a href="<?php echo $parentpost_link ?>"><?php echo $parentcat_name; ?></a></h2>
```

---

The strange thing is that this works ok with one or two categories. While on another occation, when in a child category post, it fails to find that there is a parentcategory.

There is a similar problem with identifying a parentcategory's first childcategory, but I suppose the reason is similar to my problems with this one.

What I want is:

1. To get the ID of the childcategory, either the one that the current post belongs to, or the only child category of this post. Then I make a slideshow consisting of all the posts in this category
2. If the current post is a child-category, I need the ID of that category. The posts should not belong to more than max 2 categories: if the first found is the wrong one, I continue to find the next, which should be the correct one.
3. If the post is in a child-category, I also want to find the permalink to the first post in the parentcategory, for navigation. This last task has also been a great difficulty. Strangely, this works perfectly with the first parent-child categories I set up, but not so with the other categories, although the database structure is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the logic. A post may have several terms, not all of which will be child terms. For instance, consider the `parent > child` term relationships:

```
a > b > c
d > e
f
```

And let's suppose that our post has the terms `c`,`e` and `f` attached to them.

Now the following loop goes through `c`,`e` and `f` in turn. But the `$parentcat` (and `$parentcat_nam`) value are over-ridden by each time:

```
 foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) {
            $parentcat = $childcat->category_parent;
            $parentcat_name = get_cat_name($parentcat);
    }
```

So the `$parentcat` will be set to the ID of the parent of the *last* term in `get_the_category()`. If that were `c` it would the ID of `b`. But if it were `f`, it would 0 and so 'fails to find a parent category'.

It's not clear what you want to do in the case of multiple terms with parents. If you want just one parent, then you can `break` out of the `foreach` loop.

```
 foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) {
            if( !empty($childcat->category_parent) ){
                $parentcat = $childcat->category_parent;
                $parentcat_name = get_cat_name($parentcat);
                break;
            }
    }
    //$parentcat is set the ID of the parent of one of the terms, 0 if all terms have no parent.
```

If you wanted to store the IDs of all parents of the post's terms, you can store them in an array

```
 $parentcat_arr=array();
 foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) {
            if( !empty($childcat->category_parent) ){
                $parentcat_arr[] = $childcat->category_parent;
                break;
            }
    }
  //$parentcat_arr stores array of IDs corresponding to the parents of the post's terms
  //If its empty, then the post has no terms with parents.
```

Comment: I am honestly not sure I understand all of your points here, but then I am not that experienced in these things. I've been misled to believe that category parent-child relations in wordpress are unique, and that other terms would not be mingled into it.
Seems like your suggested break-solution works for finding the parents, but I still have problems finding the first post in the parent-category.

Comment: Each term has exactly one parent, yes. But if you have 2 terms, they do not necessarily have the *same* parent. In my example `c` and `e` both terms, but they have different parents.

Answer (score 0):

this is the very very simple code for showing all the parents categories ( include current category) of a post:

```
$category = get_the_category();
$current_category = $category[0];
echo get_category_parents($current_category, TRUE, ' &raquo; ');
```